Update token logo
I need help updating my token logo on Solscan. When I try to update it, I see an error message saying "Immutable denied."

The asset metadata was probably marked as immutable during creation and cannot be updated.
This is marked by a isMutable field during asset creation with umi, more info https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/update
